# Yii CJuiAutoComplete data from Ajax request does not display list choice

Tags: autocomplete, yii

Autocomplete does not display data from sourceUrl;

Controller

```
public function actionTestAutoComplete() {
        $r = array(
                array("label"=>"Test 1", "value"=>"Test 1") ,
                array("label"=>"Test 2", "value"=>"Test 2") ,
                array("label"=>"Test 3", "value"=>"Test 3") ,
                array("label"=>"Test 4", "value"=>"Test 4") ,
            );
        echo CJSON::encode($r);
    }
```

View

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name' => 'test_autocomplete',
                'source'=>$this->createUrl("testAutocomplete"),
                'value' => "",
                'options' => array(
                    'minChars'=>1,
                    'autoFill'=>false,
                    'focus'=> 'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#test_autocomplete" ).val( ui.item.label );
                        return false;
                    }',
                    'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        return false;
                    }'
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array( 'autocomplete'=>'off'),
            ));
```

The action testAutocomplete works in debug, but the autocomplete does not display data from ajax.

The code bellow work fine.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name' => 'test_autocomplete',
                'source'=>array(
                             array('label'=>'test 1', 'value'=>'teste 1'),
                             array('label'=>'test 2', 'value'=>'teste 2'),
                             array('label'=>'test 3', 'value'=>'teste 3'),
                          ),
                'value' => "",
                'options' => array(
                    'minChars'=>1,
                    'autoFill'=>false,
                    'focus'=> 'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#test_autocomplete" ).val( ui.item.label );
                        return false;
                    }',
                    'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        return false;
                    }'
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array( 'autocomplete'=>'off'),
            ));
```

Please, I need help,

Thanks

Comment: Are there any javascript/ajax errors perhaps?

Comment: yes check the ajax errors, maybe you have not added action to accessrules

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have tested this and it works fine.

On view side code...

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name' => 'test_autocomplete',
                'source'=>$this->createUrl('Controller class name here/AutoCompleteLookup'), // always define the correct path in Url..
                'value' => "",
                'options' => array(
                    'minChars'=>1,
                    'autoFill'=>false,
                    'focus'=> 'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#test_autocomplete" ).val( ui.item.label );
                        return false;
                    }',
                    'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        return false;
                    }'
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array( 'autocomplete'=>'off'),
            )); ?>
```

The rest of your code is OK, but here were some mistakes which I have fixed.

Comment: `createUrl` works with just actionId also, so it shouldn't be a url problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using sourceURL instead source option.